# Validate PropType without a value in React

Tags: reactjs, properties

How to validate a `propType` if I pass it without any value, just like a flag?

```
<SomeComponent somePropToValidate />
```

Would it be ok to do it like this, or is there a better way?

```
static propTypes = {
    somePropToValidate: PropTypes.bool
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add the leading `React.` for your `PropTypes`. Try this:

```
static propTypes = {
    somePropToValidate: React.PropTypes.bool
};
```

This will evaluate to a `boolean true` if your component is `<SomeComponent somePropToValidate />`.
To pass a `boolean false` simply remove the attribute or pass `false`. Like this:

```
<SomeComponent />
```

or

```
<SomeComponent somePropToValidate={false} />
```

Comment: OK, thank you, Just like I was thinking. And also: if you do `import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';` you don't need leading React.

Comment: @OlehZiniak yeh indeed. I wasn't sure if you were having an error or not, so I presumed you forgot to import